# How to get the text of the message to which the person has put a reaction. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How to get the text of the message to which the person has put a reaction? Is it possible?

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == "":
        print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [`payload`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) allows you to [get the message ID](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.message_id).

You can then convert this to the message, by getting the channel and then fetching the message. If you don't want to do this, you should just use the normal reaction add event, which provides the actual message class (but only if the message cached - see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add)).

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == "":
        message = await client.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        print(message.content)
        # prints message content, or do whatever you need
```

Comment: You allowed a little pardon, but I found it

`payload.message.id` != `payload.message_id`